# How to pass wizard fields ids in sale .order.line for Odoo10

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo, wizard

I've inherited the `sale.order.line` and I've added a wizard (`sale.pack.wizard`) accesible from a button of `sale.order` form. Besides, I have a field `test` (`One2many` type) in the wizard. Now, I want to get the `test` field IDs in a method of `sale.order.line` model. So, how can I do this?

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order.line"

    @api.depends('product_uom_qty', 'discount', 'price_unit', 'tax_id', 'product_id','price_subtotal')
    def _compute_amount(self):
        active_id = self.env.context.get('active_ids', []) or []
        new = self.env['sale.pack.wizard'].browse(active_id)
        #Here i want to show 'test' field id from wizard

class SalePackWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "sale.pack.wizard"
    _description = "Sale Pack Wizard"

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Product Pack", required=True, domain="[('is_pack','=',True)]")
    test = fields.One2many('product.gold','service',string="Pack Products",change_default=True, default=_onchange_action_product_add )
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve your purpose in that way. You have to take into account that there is a scheduled action in Odoo (*AutoVacuum osv_memory objects*) which removes every transient model record each 30 minutes (by default). This means that if you were able to get the wizard test field value, even so, it would only return any value the 30 minutes after the wizard was opened for the first time.

So, what I'd do in your case, is to create a new field in `sale.order.line` model which stores the info you need of the wizard. Then, I'd create a button in the wizard, and when you click on this button, execute a method which fills in the new `sale.order.line` field with the info you need.

Comment: I want to add condition on sales order for wizard field. But, Now i am not getting any id to that wizard field. So, what is the procedure for getting ids of wizard fields on sales order form?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. But you can't get any info from a transient model (your wizard), unless you need this info only during a short period of time, and I guess that this is not your case because you seem to be trying to get the transient model info in the compute method of a field (which needs persistent data).

Comment: Yes, i am trying that.